# SnowSQL login issue

Tags: authentication, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to login into snowSQL for the first time and i am getting this below error. I want to know what is wrong with the below statement.

snowsql -a LTA43954.US-west-oregon.aws -u INDUMATHI

and the error is

250001 (n/a): Could not connect to Snowflake backend after 0 attempt(s).Aborting
If the error message is unclear, enable logging using -o log_level=DEBUG and see the log to find out the cause. Contact support for further help.

Please help me out

Answer (score 0):

Is your snowflake instance up?
Also check your region, if you are using correct one. I checked on oregon, looks like its us-west-2. Please try using that and see if it works.
You can also try to put all this in your snowflake config file and just type snowsql (without any parameters) and it should log you in.
The default location for config file is your homedirectory/.snowsql/config
On windows - c:\users<username>.snowsql\config

```
accountname = LTA43954
region = US-west-oregon.aws
username = INDUMATHI
password =
```

Password you can provide in config file or you will be prompted for it.

I tested connectivity using same and it gave me password prompt, so it means its working. Please refer below for the test I did.
[image]

It appears your snowflake instance was not up or had some issue/outage, as now its connecting fine.

Answer (score 0):

The account name has an incorrect region id appended to it. It should be as follows:

`snowsql -a LTA43954.us-west-2 -u INDUMATHI`

Try this and verify